# Show content inline in a cell of a bootstrap 4 table on a large display.

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I have a table with a couple of columns. In tha last column (on the right) I have some buttons that I want to show up next to each other on large screen. I can't get it to work. I tried setting the class of the `td` elemnt to `d-inline` to make the content appear inline, but it does not work. I also tried creating a `div` with the css set to show it inline, but again it did not work. How to fix this so all content of the cell shows inline on a large screen?

**My HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
<tr>
  <td>
    some long text here, well at least long enough to show the effect of the buttons next being next to each other anymore, even on a large display. 
    </td>
  <td>
    something else here
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Or as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpmcwsto/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a `style="white-space:nowrap"` style on the table column, which should force things not to wrap inside the cell.

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
<tr>
  <td>
    some long text here, well at least long enough to show the effect of the buttons next being next to each other anymore, even on a large display. 
    </td>
  <td>
    something else here
  </td>
  <td style="white-space:nowrap">
    <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgv9e0jw/

Alternatively, since you're already using Bootstrap, you can also use their provided `text-nowrap` class, which does essentially the same thing as above.

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
<tr>
  <td>
    some long text here, well at least long enough to show the effect of the buttons next being next to each other anymore, even on a large display. 
    </td>
  <td>
    something else here
  </td>
  <td class="text-nowrap">
    <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm">
    some button
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ympe2g7w/

Comment: That works quite well, thank you. Do you know if there is any class that does this only on large displays? Of course, I could make a css class with a media rule for this, but maybe it already exists?

Comment: Actually maybe, you could make the buttons flex items and change "text-nowrap" to "d-flex flex-wrap flex-lg-nowrap". There might be a "text-lg-nowrap" class but it's not in the doc that I can find. Otherwise media queries would be your best bet